# x64_64 NASM call printf raises segfault

Tags: assembly, printf, x86-64, nasm

When trying to use external C function in assembly, I have segfaults without knowing why.
Does it have something to do with stack alignement ? I can't find the right documentation (a link will be highy appreciated).

My code :

```
extern printf

section .data
int_string: db "hey, your result is %d", 10, 0
global main
main:
    push rbp
    mov rbp, rsp
    mov rax, 78
    push rbp
    mov rdi, int_string
    mov rsi, rax ; 78 in rsi
    call printf
    pop rbp
    mov rax, 1
    leave
    ret
```

I compile using :

```
nasm -f elf64 test.asm 
gcc -no-pie -fno-pie test.o -o test
./test
```

Note that this *sometimes* works.

My working environment :
Linux (ubuntu)
Intel i7

Comment: Yep, classic stack alignment problem.  Will link you to an appropriate duplicate.

Comment: "Sometimes works" sounds very unlikely, unless you're talking about changing the source.  If this segfaults at all, it should segfault every time you run the program, as RSP % 16 == 8 is guaranteed on entry to any function, including `main`.  (And thus RSP%16 == 0 is required *before* a call)

Comment: @fuz I had already seen that thread and still can't fix my problem. Since the syntax is different, I don't get to make it work.

Comment: In simplest terms, change your code to have an **odd** number of `push` instructions before the call to printf. You currently have 2. Remove the second push, which is unnecessary, and remove the corresponding pop.